# SQL Native Client 10.0 Login Failed

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, asp-classic

I'm setting up a Classic ASP site in IIS 7.5 (Windows Server 2008 R2). I set the site and the application pool to run as a specific domain account. I added the domain account to the SQL Server 2008 instance running on the same server. I'm getting the following error:

`[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\Account'.`

Here is my connection string:

`Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=server;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Database=db`

I have the exact same setup on another site on the same server. The other site works flawlessly. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User error. I was editing the wrong file.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that a Windows authentication SQL Server login exists for the Windows NT/Windows 2000 user account that IIS uses to process the request for the ASP page.

read [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307002/en-us).